# SQL limit query optimization

Tags: mysql, asp-classic

I have a mailing list that contains 4000,000 emails, members of my website enter the email and i take it after this i do a validation of this email with 4 million mailing list , to do this i wrote a code that paging the emails that return from sql query but when the data goes to the next page i see the error that the page fall into a time out . i wrote the code by using asp

```
If Session("oturumlar") = "" Then
set Toplam = adoCon.execute("SELECT count(id) AS intToplam from temiz2;" )
Session("kayitsayi") = CLng(Toplam("intToplam"))
Session("oturumlar") = "oturdu"
Toplam.close
End If

intKayitSayisi = Session("kayitsayi")
intListelenecek = 30
intSayfaSayisi = Yuvarla(CLng(intKayitSayisi) / CLng(intListelenecek)) 

intGecerliSayfa = Request.QueryString("sayfa") 

LimitKodu = intGecerliSayfa*intListelenecek 
LimitKodu = LimitKodu-intListelenecek 

intLooper = 0

strSQL = "SELECT eposta, id FROM temiz2 ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT "& LimitKodu &", "& intListelenecek
Set uye = adoCon.execute(strSQL)
```

how i can optimize a limit in sql query?

Comment: First thing that came to my mind: is "id" primary key & identity if not does it have an index?

Answer (score 0):

adoCon.commandtimeout = 30 'no of seconds